# mySQL Group by member name

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to fetch list of who messaged a user or who user messaged to.

```
SELECT messages.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(lastseen) AS lastseen 
    FROM messages
    WHERE '".$user."' IN (from,to)
    GROUP BY IF ('".$user."' = from,to,from)
) AS latest
LEFT JOIN messages 
USING(lastseen) 
ORDER BY lastseen desc,(read='no' and to='".$user."') limit 10
```

This works, however, it shows some users twice.

[image]

What is the correct way to show a user only once ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
SELECT messages.* 
  FROM 
  (SELECT MAX(lastseen) AS lastseen,IF ('Tom' = `from`,`to`,`from`) as otheruser FROM messages
    WHERE 'Tom' IN (`from`,`to`) GROUP BY otheruser
   )
AS latest INNER JOIN messages ON latest.lastseen = messages.lastseen
                             AND (('Tom' = messages.from AND latest.otheruser = messages.to)
                                 OR
                                 ('Tom' = messages.to AND latest.otheruser = messages.from))
ORDER BY messages.lastseen
DESC,`read`='no' limit 10
```

just replace 'Tom' with your variable

This will return the latest 10 users that messaged to 'Tom' or 'Tom' messaged to.

Comment: I have tried your code, but it gave me the exactly same results.

Comment: what do you mean by same user twice? it's going to show different names that messaged to or messaged from user 'Tom'.

Comment: unless you have same user who messaged Tom twice at the same second(time)

Comment: if so you might want to use a max(id) where id is an auto_incremented id for messages instead of of max(lastseen).